# Visa application for PhD studies Australia

Tags: visa, australia

I want to commence my PhD studies in Melbourne as an international student. I have come to know that I need to enroll my child in australian school for submitting visa application via homeaffairs website. 
Can anyone tell me any government or affordable school in melbourne? 
Also tell how to submit my application for admission online for my 6-7 year child? 
Please advice soon.

Answer (score 2):

## All state schools in Australia are free. Just enrol your kid in one that’s close to your house so that it’s convenient to drop them off.

Australian schools fall into one of three categories: state schools run by the state government, which are free (though they might charge a small enrolment fee), independent schools which might or might not charge their students for tuition, and Catholic schools which also may or may not charge tuition fees.

Comment: Can you please suggest a flat/apartment/home in muslim community in melbourne australia? And accordingly a state school near that region? My income is 2000 $ per month.

Comment: @anonymous090 I'm pretty sure that'd be outside the scope of this site. I'd recommend talking to a real estate agent based there.

Comment: Try the Whirlpool discussion forum @anonymous 090. Stop asking the same question and spamming this group - https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/search?q=melbourne+schools&f=&fg=-1&w=&p=